# System volume control reaches max volume pretty fast

Tags: alsa, volume-control

I am using Xubuntu 18.04.1 and have a problem with my system audio level. The volume control max volume is reached pretty fast, at ca 6% of the volume control bar.

This leaves me with roughly three states for my system volume:

```
0% -> no sound
1% - 6% -> loud sound (maybee 2 steps in volume level)
7% - 100% -> very loud sound (no change above 6%)
```

The volume control is adjustable via UI, via keyboard shortcut or directly via alsamixer - all show the same behaviour. I use the PCIe soundcard Asus Xonar 5.1 DGX in multichannel mode.

Has anyone an idea how to fix this behaviour ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have this exact same issue... lol